# How to access innerHTML of a div produced after some other process takes place using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to access the innerHTML property of a div, the text inside which is generated after some function is executed.
Say, for example, I have this login mechanism:

```
   <?php
        $message = "";

        if(isset($_POST['user'] ) )  
            $user = $_POST['user'];
        if(isset($_POST['pass']))  {
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];


        if($user == "ans" && $pass == "ans" )
        {
            $message = "success";
        }

        else 
            $message = "fail";

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="msgDiv">
                <?php
                    if(isset($message) )
                        echo $message;
                ?>
</div>
    <form  action="#" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="user" class="user">

            <input type="text" name="pass" class="user">

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="submit">
    </form>


    <script>

            var user = document.getElementsByClassName('user')[0];
            var pass = document.getElementsByClassName('user')[1];
            var button = document.getElementById('button');
            var msg = document.getElementsByClassName('msgDiv');
            button.onclick= function()
            {
                user.value= "ans";
                pass.value="an";

                msg.onchange = function()  {
                alert(msg.textContent);
                } //THIS CODE IS WRONG, I SUPPOSE
            }   



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The text in the "msgDiv" will be generated only when either the login succeeds or fails.
How can I fetch this generated text using DOM functions?

Comment: `document.getElementById('msgDiv').textContent`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("msgDiv").textContent`

```js
function modifier(){
    document.getElementById("msgDiv").textContent = "message";
}

modifier();

console.log(document.getElementById("msgDiv").textContent);
```

```html
<div id="msgDiv"></div>
    <form>
     <input type="text" name="user">
     <input type="password" name="password">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

**EDIT:** The `#button` is bound with 2 events: one is `form` submission and other is the `onclick` function you have written to `alert` the response string `message`. So now when you are clicking on the `submit` button the `form` is getting submitted and probably your `msgDiv` is showing the response message. And, since you have written your `alert` function inside your `onclick` event, clicking it again will eventually trigger another form submission.

You can simply write `<?php if(isset($message)){echo "alert('".$message."');";} ?>`

**EDIT 2:**

1. No need to initialize `$message`. Remove or comment out the line `$message = "";`
2. Add `<?php if(isset($message)){echo "alert('".$message."');";} ?>` just before closing the `script` tag. This will `alert` the `message` value whenever it is set after `form` submission.

Comment: But how can I access the property when the function generating the text  is executed after clicking the submit button? I  have already tried your approach but it's not working.

Comment: if you are making an asynchronous request, you will be able to access it using `document.getElementById("msgDiv").textContent`

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal We'll need your javascript code to help you with the javascript logic. You should edit it into your original post.

Comment: @Tyler , Here is a summarised code of  what I have been doing

Comment: @YogeshMistry, This would have worked for me, but the problem here actually is (sorry, I forgot to mention it earlier) that my posted code is actually a part of a chrome extension I am trying to code, so I can't implement your suggestion. The form I have posted above is part of a page in which I have to inject my extension's code and the JS part is part of my extension's code

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for the suggestion! Maybe I can figure out a way to implement your suggestion @YogeshMistry

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal actually you just need to do few things. first, comment out the line `$message=""` and then add the line `<?php if(isset($message)){echo "alert('".$message."');";} ?>` before closing the `script` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have get the element with `getElementById(id)` and then access the innerHTML property with `.innerHTML`. Depending on exactly what you want, you might be looking for innerText or textContent.

Quick notes about innerHTML, innerText, and textContent:

innerHTML can alter the actual html elements on the page, including removing or adding elements.

innerText will get or set plain text to elements; however, is aware of certain situations and may leave out some text.

textContent will get everything as plain text.

```
var $ = function(id){
    //commonly used function to easily access html elements from javascript
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

$("msgDiv").innerHTML = "something";
```